# Java no-argument constructor: Throw impossible exception, or have empty catch block?

Tags: java, exception, constructor

Is it better that a no-argument constructor throws an impossible exception or has an empty catch block?  Let's say I have a class like this.

```
public class Foo {
    private int num;
    private String numString;

    public Foo() throws NumberFormatException {
        setNum("1");
    }

    public void setNum(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
        // In reality, complex code goes here
        num = Integer.parseInt(s);
        numString = s;
    }
}
```

The compiler forces the constructor to either throw NumberFormatException (which would never happen) or have a try/catch block. However, would it be correct to have an empty catch block, which is usually frowned upon?

```
public Foo() {
    try {
        setNum("1");
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException e) { }
}
```

Please note that Foo would be a library class and others would use it, so having a no-argument constructor throw an impossible exception would be confusing. Also note that the real exception is a custom exception, not NumberFormatException, which might make things even more confusing for the library user, who might feel like they have to read up on the custom exception when it is not necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NumberFormatException` is a `RuntimeException`, so you don't need to list it on your `throws` clause -- just pretend it's not there. That goes for both the method and the constructor.

Any subclass of `RuntimeException` (including `RuntimeException` itself) is an "unchecked exception," which means the compiler won't force you to check for it in a try/catch clause. In contrast, any `Exception` which is not a subclass of `RuntimeException` is called, easily enough, a checked exception.

If it *were* a checked exception (that is, not a subclass of `RuntimeException`), but you were sure that you could never trigger it, then it'd be safe to catch it. Rather than completely swallowing it, it'd be best to wrap it around an unchecked exception.

```
try {
    thisCodeCanNeverThrowAnIOException();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e); // juuust in case!
}
```

Now your code compiles, doesn't have a `throws` clause for an exception you never expect to be thrown, and yet will not hide a serious error if, by some bug or future change, that exception does end up getting thrown.

(Note to those reading the comments: I originally had in the code example `throw new RuntimeException(e)`, but Stephen C and Peter Lawrey pointed out that, in Java 1.4.2 and newer, AssertionError is better).

Comment: +1 - I prefer to throw "AssertionError" which has the more specific meaning of "this should never happen".

Comment: @StephenC The problem with that is that `AssertionError` can't take a `Throwable cause` argument, which means you won't have the stack trace that shows you how the first exception go thrown. That's extremely helpful debugging information, especially if you were sure it couldn't have gotten thrown!

Comment: My real exception is a checked exception, and re-throwing it as a RuntimeException worked! Thanks!

Comment: Rethrowing a checked exception wrapped in an unchecked exception such as `RuntimeException` is a time-honored tradition. As long as the client code doesn't catch `Throwable` or `Exception` to be swallowed, programming errors will eventually be logged or reported. Some have argued that the concept of checked vs. unchecked exceptions has created a culture of ignoring real problems. Putting a sensible exception policy in place is paramount to building a robust application.

Comment: @yshavit - That is no longer correct.  As of Java 7, `AssertError` DOES have a constructor that takes a Throwable cause - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html#AssertionError(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)

Comment: Not all checked exceptions are subclasses of RuntimeException.

Comment: @Perception sub classes of RuntimeException and Error are unchecked by definition. All other Throwable are checked.

Comment: @yshavit As of Java 1.4.2, AssertionError takes a Throwable as an argument which becomes the cause. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html#AssertionError%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @StephenC Oh wow, I never bothered to read that fine print! Good to know, thanks!

Comment: @PeterLawrey The thanks goes to you, too, except SO only lets me @-ify one user...

Comment: @PeterLawrey - too much typing after too many drinks. I did indeed mean unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Since s has to be a number why dont you pass an integer through setNum() instead of the current string? An integer is always parseable to a string.

Comment: My real method takes an array of Strings as an argument, and every String in the array needs to be validated or it throws an exception. I used this example because it is easier.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this depends your business care or personal coding style, If you choose to throw an exception it probably to be better with a owned and wrapped exception, if the parameters which you are passing in is incorrect or NOT make sense you could throw the exception right now.

Whatever the NumberFormatException MUST be thrown, this is a just decision where you get catch it. it may be in your library class, or the caller class, or somewhere you don't know. without it the program will be down.

In your case, do you consider the no-number string as a legal value, if yes it is your responsibility to keep the exception in your package.

Answer (score 0):

I would say: Never an empty catch block (whatever the case). As @yshavit points out, it's not a good practice to swallow a possible error.

Using asserts, as @stephen-c said, is a one step forward alternative BUT this solution has two disadvantages:

1. Maybe asserts are not enabled on the "operational/production" server, so what you really have is very similar to an empty catch block
2. In case they are enabled on server, an error during the execution of this piece of code will demonstrate you have a bug in your application, as far as it's somenthing not expected that appears ("this should never happen", but it happens! so...)

So my recommendation goes for @yshavit proposal.